# get owner's email for all aws resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3

I'm trying to build a script with boto3 and lambda to get the **email address of the owner for all the created resources** across regions in aws (at least EC2 to begin with). The purpose of this would be to notify the owner that they have this many resources.

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
iam = boto3.client('iam').list_users()
```

iam json has all the user information but no email address and ec2 has owner id but I'm not sure how to just get the owner id.

If there is a third party service I'm willing to consider that as well.

Comment: Not all resources are created by users...many (even most i dare say) are created by assumed roles - meaning there is no email to physical person association.

Comment: In that case, is it possible to get the ARN of the role or user id created that resource?

Comment: may be worth creating a CloudTrail and polling the event from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no concept of "resource ownership" in AWS.

Rather, when a user makes an API call (or uses the console) to create resources, AWS confirms that they have permission to make the API call. If so, then the resources are created and **the resources belong to the AWS account**. There is no link to the user that requested the resources.

The **AWS CloudTrail** service keeps an audit log of API calls, so it would be possible to examine the CloudTrail records to see which user made the API call that created a resource.

Some people prefer using **tags** to keep track of the ownership or purpose of a resource. For example, using tags to track department, project or cost center.

Also, please note that resources could be created by **IAM Users, IAM Roles** (that are assumed by users, which is also traceable via CloudTrail) or other **AWS services** (eg Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling launches EC2 instances automatically). So, it isn't always easy to find a 1-to-1 relationship between a resource and the 'person' that created it.